# I am trying to make matrix multiplication code in php but instead of matrix multiplication it happens just simple multiplication with row and column

Tags: php, arrays, matrix-multiplication

I want to do matrix multiplication using array in PHP I have trying to do same but instead of matrix multiplication it just happening Simple multiplication as per output please help me to resolve it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$a1 = Array('0' => Array('0' => 1,'1' => 2),'1' => Array('0' => 4,'1' => 5));

$a2 = Array('0' => Array('0' => 7,'1' => 5),'1' => Array('0' => 3,'1' => 2));

$sumArray = array();

$result = array();
for($i=0; $i<=1; $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<=1; $j++)
    {
        $result[$i][$j] = $a1[$i][$j] * $a2[$i][$j];
    }
}
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

[array image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP3Z9.png)

Comment: for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
    c[i][j]=0;
    for(k=0;k<2;k++)
    {
    c[i][j]=c[i][j]+(a[i][k]*b[k][j]);
    }
    }
    }

Comment: check this link http://programmingincplus.blogspot.in/2012/09/multiplication-of-two-2d-matrix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php



$a = Array('0' => Array('0' => 1,'1' => 2),'1' => Array('0' => 4,'1' => 5));


$b = Array('0' => Array('0' => 7,'1' => 5),'1' => Array('0' => 3,'1' => 2));

$sumArray = array();

$c = array();

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
 for($j=0;$j<2;$j++) 
 { 
    $c[$i][$j]=0; 
    for($k=0;$k<2;$k++) 
        { $c[$i][$j]=$c[$i][$j]+($a[$i][$k]*$b[$k][$j]); 
    } 
} 
} 


echo "<pre/>";
print_r($c);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

matrix multiplication is implemented the following way:

```
for i = 1..N
   for j = 1..N
     result[i][j] = 0.
     for k = 1..N
       result[i][j] += array1[i][k] * array2[j][k] // "row times column"
     end for
   end for
end for
```

I hope I got your question right. Matrix-Multiplication requires 3 for-loops.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with 3*3 MxM? Do you want to multiply 3 quadratic matrices, e.g. `result = A * B * C`?

Comment: Okay, if you want to multiply 3 matrices with each other use sth. like this (C++ code):

Comment: Write a fct. which takes 2 matrices as argument and returns the matrix-product (the implementation of this algorithm can be seen in my answer, return `result`). Then you call this fct twice for multiplying 3 matrices (in the second call you multiply the output of (A*B) with C).